# Finding the maximum and minimum value of a quadratic equation

Tags: python

So I've written a program that calculates the quadratic equation's zeroes but I need help formulating the way to find the biggest/lowest value, the extreme points coordinates and if its a maximum or minimum point. Grateful for all help!

Comment: A quadratic equation will have a maxima or a minima, never both. It will always be exactly between the zeros.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a new user, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [ask].
It also wouldn't hurt to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4996248).

Comment: You could differentiate the equation and find the zeroes of the derivative.

Comment: And the second derivative will tell you if it's a maximum or a minimum!  The second derivative of a function is called the 'concavity', and will be positive for a local minimum and negative for a local maximum.  The simplest quadratic equation, f(x) = x^2, has 1st derivative = 2x and 2nd derivative = 2.  Since 2 is positive, that means f(x) has positive concavity (i.e. is concave upwards, like a teacup) and the point at the bottom of the 'cup' (the zero of the function, and also of the first derivative) is a local minimum.

Comment: If you're stuck on how to implement the tests in Python, providing a sample of the code you have so far and which part isn't working for you would help us give you a better answer.  As it stands right now, this seems like more of a math question than a programming question.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck a= float (input("Assign a"))
b= float (input("Assign b"))
c= float (input("Assign c"))

p=b/a
q=c/a
x1=-p/2+((p/2)**2-q)**0.5
x2=-p/2-((p/2)**2-q)**0.5

if ((p/2)**2-q) > 0:
  print ("Zeroes are",x1,"och",x2)
elif ((p/2)**2-q) == 0:
  print ("Only one zero which is",x1,)
else:
  print ("The function has no zeroes")

Comment: Do a web search on "quadratic equation vertex coordinates formula".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [edit] the question to include any relevant code. Note well that this is **not a discussion forum** If you know the mathematical principles behind what needs to be done, then explain what part of the code you can't write yourself, and ask a *specific* question about it. Otherwise, you have a question purely about math, which is off topic here; please try [math.se].

Answer (score 2):

```
a = float(input("enter the value of coefficient 'a':   "))

b  = float(input("enter the value of coefficient 'b':  "))

c  = float(input("enter the value of coefficient 'c':  "))

z = ( b**2) - (4*a*c)

z2 = ( ( z**(1/2) )    -b )/2*a

z3 = ( -( z**(1/2) )    -b )/2*a


z4 = (-b)/2*a

z5 = (-z)/4*a

if a!=0:

    if a>0:

        print("the concavity of the parabola is facing upwards")

    else:

        print("the concavity of the parabola is facing downwards")


print("the square roots are: ", z2," and ", z3)

print("the coordinate of the maximum point is:", "( ",z4," ",z5," )")
```

Comment: In the formulae where a division by 2*a appears, you should put parentheses around 2*a ( e.g. $z2 = ( ( z**(1/2) )    -b )/(2*a)$) to avoid it being interpreted as a division by 2 whose result is multiplied by a.